# Does Mathematica apply the additivity property in Sum?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, algebraic-manipulation

I was trying to simplify a summation of two terms, as follows

```
FullSimplify[Sum[1, {n, 1, k}] + Sum[x[n], {n, 1, k}]]
```

However, the simplification was not performed as I expected:

[image: Sum_nok]

When I split the summation in two, I obtain the expected result, as follows:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

I do not understand why *Mathematica* does not apply the additivity property in the first case. Is there a procedure to include properties in *Mathematica* Functions?

**EDIT: COMPLETE ANSWER**

A complete inclusion of the additivity property in summation can be obtained by the following code:

```
Unprotect[Sum];
Sum[Plus[leftArg_, rightArg__], {variable_, argStart_, argEnd_}] := 
 Sum[Plus[leftArg], {variable, argStart, argEnd}] + 
  Sum[Plus[rightArg], {variable, argStart, argEnd}]
Protect[Sum];
```

Comment: The problem is that `Sum[1, {n, 1, k}]` is already automatically evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the Mathematica Programmers decided, that this is not nessecary. 
I for myself could also believe, that there are situations where this +1 can make it easier to get a closed expression for your sum.

But if you want to really have this functionality, you can overload it:

```
Unprotect[Sum];
Sum[Plus[leftArg_, rightArg__], {variable_, argStart_, 
   argEnd_}] := (argEnd - argStart + 1)*leftArg + 
   Sum[Plus[rightArg], {variable, argStart, argEnd}] /; 
  FreeQ[leftArg, variable]
Protect[Sum];
```

Now your Mathematica behaves like you wished:

```
Sum[x[n] + 1, {n, 1, k}]
Sum[x[n] + 1, {n, 5, k}]
```

> k + Sum[x[n], {x, 0, k}]
>
> -4 + k + Sum[x[n], {x, 5, k}]

_

**EDIT**:
Also notice, that for Mathematica, this isn't a simplification. They're are actual equally complex:

```
LeafCount[Sum[x[n] + 1, {n, 1, k}]] == LeafCount[k + Sum[x[n], {n, 1, k}]]
```

> True

Comment: That's solved my problem! Thank you very much!