# Why does this simple ratio of products not simplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, products

Why does this ratio of products not Simplify to a[n]?

```
Clear[a,k,n]
$Assumptions={n>1}
Simplify[ Product[a[k], {k, 1, n}] / Product[a[k], {k, 1, n - 1}] ]
```

Setting an actual value of $n$, it works fine, e.g. set n=5 and you get a[5].
If you define a function a[k] it seems to sometimes work fine. It doesn't work for

```
Product[1 - 1/Sqrt[k], {k, 2, n}] / Product[1 - 1/Sqrt[k], {k, 2, n - 1}]
```

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136657/does-mathematica-apply-the-additivity-property-in-sum -- Many general properties of sums and products are not implemented, so it seems.  There are some other related Q&A as well.

Answer (score 2):

General properties of products and sums do not seem to be implemented in *Mathematica*.  You can implement them through `Simplify` using the option `TransformationFunctions`, provided the property results in a "simpler" expression.

For example:

```
productProperties = {HoldPattern[
      Product[a_, {k_, k1_, k2_}]/Product[a_, {k_, k3_, k4_}]] /; 
     BooleanQ[Simplify[k1 <= k3]] && BooleanQ[Simplify[k2 < k4]] :>
      If[Simplify[k1 <= k3], Product[a, {k, k1, k3 - 1}], 
      1/Product[a, {k, k3, k1 - 1}]]*
     If[Simplify[k2 < k4], 1/Product[a, {k, k2 + 1, k4}], 
      Product[a, {k, k4 + 1, k2}]]};

Simplify[Product[a[k], {k, 1, n}]/Product[a[k], {k, 1, n - 1}], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. productProperties &}]

(*  a[n]  *)
```

You can add properties to `productProperties` as desired.

If you like the approach in [Does Mathematica apply the additivity property in Sum?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136657/does-mathematica-apply-the-additivity-property-in-sum), you can also extend the definition of `Product` by translating the property above into a function definition:

```
Unprotect[Product];
Product /: Product[a_, {k_, k1_, k2_}]/Product[a_, {k_, k3_, k4_}] /; 
   BooleanQ[Simplify[k1 <= k3]] && BooleanQ[Simplify[k2 < k4]] :=
  If[Simplify[k1 <= k3], Product[a, {k, k1, k3 - 1}], 
    1/Product[a, {k, k3, k1 - 1}]]*
   If[Simplify[k2 < k4], 1/Product[a, {k, k2 + 1, k4}], 
    Product[a, {k, k4 + 1, k2}]];
Protect[Product];
```

Now the transformation happens automatically, without needing to apply `Simplify`:

```
Product[a[k], {k, 1, n}]/Product[a[k], {k, 1, n - 1}]
(*  a[n]  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. The result is 1 - 1/Sqrt[5].

Are you defining n before asking for the second ratio? (e.g. n=5).

Comment: Hi, no, n is not defined in the second one. It does work for 1-1/k (n undefined). Wierd.